# Restcomm Smsc Gateway: Giving only 50tps on single connection

Tags: smpp, restcomm, jsmpp

I am using Restcomm smsc gateway 7.3.135.  When both client and server were running on same machine, I am getting only 50 tps on single connection.

In the document I have read we can get upto 1000tps.  Please guide how can I achieve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

the community edition of restcomm projects is not performance tested, only the product is going through those performance tests as it requires a lot of fine tuning in the project itself, logging, OS, JVM Options, it also depends on the hardware you're running. You should may want to contact Telestax to get help on that as it's usually pretty involved.